# Don't allow linebreaks in EditTexts

Tags: android, android-edittext, line-breaks

I would like to limit the maximum amount of letters and disallow linebreaks in my EditText on Android.

I know that I can limit the characters by using

```
android:maxLength="..."
```

But is there a way to disallow linebreaks? If I use

```
singleLine="true"
```

is there still a linebreak character in my

```
editText.getText().toString()
```

?

Comment: Can not you check yourself??

Comment: It would take longer than to just ask the question, maybe someone else wants to know it, too. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO there will be no line break if you use

```
  singleLine="true"
```

So using this option is suitable if one wants no line break

Answer (score 1):

Add  `android:maxLines="1"` in your `edittext` tag as

```
<EditText 
 .....
android:maxLines="1" // add here
</EditText>
```

And also `android:singleLine="true"` should work.